# Incorrect spacing around headers

Tags: feature-request, design

When we use a header in a Question or Answer, the header is starting a *new* section of text, and is not related to the previous text above it (we have bold etc for highlighting within *current* text).

However, currently the space above the header is less than the space below it, so the header visually appears to be more closely linked and relevant to the text above the header.

For example:

---

Here I write some text about conservation within urban areas.

### Header to portray I'm starting a new context (or other usage)

Do mice understand algebra when given enhancement drugs?

---

The header is closer to the text above than it is the text it's relevant to below.
I measured it's roughly 5 pixels more space from the bottom of the header to the next text, than it is from the top of the header to the text above.

Can we have the spacing slightly adjusted so (whatever space is decided) there is more above the header than below?

Something like:  `margin-top: 1.5em;` would do it (i.e. on `h2{}`)

This is what the exact above example looks like with 1.5 em added to the top (using Firebug):
[image: 1.5em-top-margin]

It's not much, but it's enough to separate the text correctly.

Comment: I never noticed that before....but now I will not be able to *un*notice it. +1

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you could add extra space *before* the headline by using `<br><br>`between the previous line and the header.

Either add it at the end of the previous line:

```
Here I write some text about conservation within urban areas.<br><br>
#Header to portray I'm starting a new context (or other usage)#
```

or on a separate line between the previous line and the header:

```
Here I write some text about conservation within urban areas.
<br><br>
#Header to portray I'm starting a new context (or other usage)#
```

This is how it looks with a `h1` header:

---

Here I write some text about conservation within urban areas.

## Header to portray I'm starting a new context (or other usage)

Do mice understand algebra when given enhancement drugs?

---

And this is how it looks with a `h2` header:

---

Here I write some text about conservation within urban areas.

### Header to portray I'm starting a new context (or other usage)

Do mice understand algebra when given enhancement drugs?

---